# Waiting for a file to be loaded in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, file, timer

I am reading files from disc that have information I need to display to the user.  I set up an event listener that flags when the file is loaded- that's easy.  However, that adds a delay before I can display the information, and it appears that doing a simple loop in the main code to wait for the file to be loaded does not work:

```
while (fileComplete == false);
```

Essentially that simply freezes the code- the file does not load while that loop functions. I can add a timer that checks every few milliseconds to see if fileComplete == true, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash is by default single-threaded, this means if you're initiating an asynchronous process, you need to release the code flow for Flash engine to actually complete the process. Doing an infinite loop like yours does NOT release the code flow, so you should drop this idea. Instead, you should either blindly wait for `Event.COMPLETE` event and do the post-load actions in the listener, or you should listen for `Event.ENTER_FRAME` and check for the flag you're setting in `Event.COMPLETE` listener. The former approach is cleaner.

Comment: Is there a way to get past that "default single-threaded" situation?

Comment: Yes, but in this particular situation you'd better go with pseudo-multitasking Flash provides. The actual difference between your file being loaded completely and the `Event.COMPLETE` dispatch will be as small as a quantum of time (one frame's delay), which is normally small emough for Flash applications. And the actual multithreading will likely make you build complicated stuff just to make it run properly, even if not doing anything.

Comment: Thanks- found some references to pseudo-multitasking routines, will pursue this path. I find it interesting that Flash appears to be multitasking while AS3 does not.

Comment: Flash has an event-driven model with one event happening at a constant rate (`Event.ENTER_FRAME`) and others appearing on demand. Pseudo-multitasking is normally implemented via manager enterframe listener, or many enterframe listeners, each making its own part of per-frame actions, and it requires that enter frame events, as well as all the other events, are processed within as less time as possible. The approach with infinite loop breaks this paradigm, the situation is similar to Windows 95's known bug of floppy disk or CD reading failure hanging up the system, since the driver used...

Comment: a similar loop to wait for the physical device to reposition itself in order to read the problematic sector from the physical media, and did not allow Windows kernel to process other tasks while waiting. Future versions of Windows have employed a return in the corresponding code, so that if the driver has encountered an error, it will set flash for itself for future processing of the error, returned the control to the OS kernel notifying it about the need to often call a certain code that's handling device errors, so that OS could process other tasks while waiting for the device to get ready.